# Solving the following inhomogeneous mathematical model which is a inhomogeneous PDE with homogeneous BC's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Solving the following inhomogeneous mathematical model which is a inhomogeneous PDE with homogeneous BC's

$$u_{xx}+u_{yy} = \cosh(\pi y) \cos(\pi x) $$
$$u_x(0,y) = u_x (1,y) = 0$$
$$u_y(x,0) = 0 $$
$$u(x,1) = 100x(1-x)$$

First we let $u(x,y) = \cosh(\pi y) \cos(\pi x)$

The Eigen value for the homogeneous problem.

$$X'(x)+\lambda X(x) = 0$$ 
$$X'(0) = X (1) = 0 $$

My problem that I am having is determining the following. I understand that you need to consider the cases $\lambda =0, \lambda< 0 , \lambda >0.$ Its the case $\lambda=0$ I am having trouble with. I understand the answer is the following from the case when $\lambda > 0 $

$$\lambda _n = \pi ^2 n^2, X_n(x) = f\cos(n\pi x)\Big|_{n=0}^{\infty}$$

**$\lambda = 0$**

$$X''(x) = 0 $$
$$X(x) = cx +d$$
$$X'(x) = c$$
$$X'(0)=0=c$$
$$X'(1)=0=c$$

So why isn't $d$ a constant?

Comment: Let $u(x,y) = \cosh(\pi y) \cos(\pi x)$? You sure?? What is X?

Answer (score 0):

$$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=\cosh{\pi{y}}\cos{\pi{x}}$$
The boundary condition in $x$ cries to expand
$$u(x, y)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}s_{n}(y)\cos{\pi{n}{x}}$$
This gives
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\partial_{y}^{2}-(\pi{n})^{2})s_{n}(y)\cos{\pi{n}{x}}=\cosh{\pi{y}}\cos{\pi{x}}$$
Now, multiply by $\cos{\pi{m}{x}}$ and integrate on $[0, 1]$ to give
$$(\partial_{y}^{2}-(\pi{m})^{2})s_{m}(y)=\delta_{1m}\cosh{\pi{y}}$$
Thus
$$s_{m}(y)=a_{m}\cosh{\pi{m}y}+b_{m}\sinh{\pi{m}y}+\delta_{1m}\frac{y\sinh{\pi{y}}}{2\pi}$$
Now, using $\partial_{y}s_{m}(0)=0$, we have $b_{m}=0$. Thus
$$u(x, y)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}\cosh{\pi{n}y}\cos{\pi{n}{x}}+\frac{y\sinh{\pi{y}}\cos{\pi{x}}}{2\pi}$$
Now, $u(x, 1)=f(x)$, this is
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}\cosh{\pi{n}}\cos{\pi{n}{x}}+\frac{\sinh{\pi}\cos{\pi{x}}}{2\pi}$$
Thus
$$a_{0}=2\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$$
$$a_{1}=\frac{2\pi}{2\pi\cosh{\pi}+\sinh{\pi}}\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\cos{\pi{x}}dx$$
and
$$a_{n}=\frac{1}{\cosh{\pi{n}}}\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\cos{\pi{n}{x}}dx, \ n\neq0, 1$$